# Dynamically allocate an array of struct containing a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, libxml2

I'm trying to read settings values from an XML file and to make things simpler I set up a struct containing every value. One of these is an array of structs. I then initialize the struct as an array.

While running the code I sometimes get a smooth run, sometimes a segfault and sometimes an abort trap (`malloc: *** error for object: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6`). I guess this is undefined behaviour.

I might have a hint on why this happens, but I couldn't get any confirmations, though I did heavy research.

In my opinion, this is caused by the allocation of space for the array of struct allocating enough memory to contain a struct with some values plus an empty array of structs. I then allocate memory for the second array of struct, therefore changing the space needed for the first array of structs.

These are the declaration of the structs:

```cpp
struct Delegate {

  int warnings;

  gchar *name;

};

struct Staff {

  gchar *president;
  gchar *vice;
  gchar *mod;

};

struct Committee {

  int n_delegate;

  gchar *name;
  gchar *topics[2];

  struct Delegate *delegates;
  struct Staff staff;


};
```

And here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
static void load_prop() {

  xmlDocPtr doc;
  xmlNodePtr node;
  xmlNodePtr subnode;
  xmlNodePtr subsubnode;
  xmlNodePtr subsubsubnode;
  xmlChar *cnumber;

  doc = xmlParseFile("/Users/username/Documents/Obermun/DebateProgram/res/xml/property.xml");
  node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

  edition = (char *) xmlGetProp(node, (const xmlChar *) "edition");

  int const index = atoi((const char*)(xmlGetProp(node, (const xmlChar *) "committees")));
  committees = (Committee *) malloc(sizeof(Committee)*index);

  subnode = node -> xmlChildrenNode;
  int i = 0;
  int t = 0;
  int d = 0;

  while(subnode != NULL) {

    if(!xmlStrcmp(subnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "committee")) {

      committees[i].name = (char *) xmlGetProp(subnode, (const xmlChar *) "name");
      committees[i].n_delegate = atoi((const char*) xmlGetProp(subnode, (const xmlChar *) "delegates"));
      committees[i].delegates = (Delegate *) malloc(sizeof(Delegate)*committees[i].n_delegate);

      subsubnode = subnode -> xmlChildrenNode;

      while(subsubnode != NULL) {

        if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "topic")) {

          committees[i].topics[t] = (char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1);
          t++;

        }

        else if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "delegate")) {

          committees[i].delegates[d].warnings = atoi((const char*) xmlGetProp(subsubnode, (const xmlChar *) "warnings"));
          committees[i].delegates[d].name = (char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1);
          d++;

        }

        else if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "staff")) {

          subsubsubnode = subsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode;

          while(subsubsubnode != NULL) {

            if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "president")) {

              committees[i].staff.president = (char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1);

            }

            if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "vice")) {

              committees[i].staff.vice = (char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1);

            }

            if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "mod")) {

              committees[i].staff.mod = (char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1);

            }

            subsubsubnode = subsubsubnode -> next;

          }

        }

        subsubnode = subsubnode -> next;

      }

      i++;

    }

    subnode = subnode -> next;

  }

}
```

Trying to debug the code with `gdb` I get this backtrace:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff7353ab66 in ?? () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff7353ab66 in ?? () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
#1  0x00007fff73705080 in pthread_kill () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
#2  0x00007fff734961ae in abort () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#3  0x0000003000000010 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007ffeffffffdf in ?? ()
#5  0xffffffff0160f658 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000010160f658 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007ffeefbff5f0 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fff7359fb58 in szone_error () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

Comment: @uneven_mark I'm compiling with g++, so it's C++. I've updated the tags as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: I was actually going to "edit tags" and change the tag to "C".  Q: Any reason you tagged "C++" instead of "C"?  ALSO: 1) Please update your post with a stack trace, and note the line it's crashing in your source code.  2)  I suspect not allocating space for "*name" could be the problem.  Q: Any reason you don't do an [strdup()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) copy from XML properties into *name?

Comment: Then you should be made aware that the code is written as if it was C. There are several things that you should not do in C++, e.g. writing `struct` before a type name in a variable declaration is pointless and potentially problematic in C++ or e.g. using C-style casts when it should be `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` or using `malloc` instead of `new`.

Comment: @Lorenzo Moscati - g++ can and will compile a "C" program as "C".  Just give the source file a suffix of ".c", instead of ".cpp".

Comment: @paulsm4 If you call `g++` instead of `gcc` without further options it will compile as C++, even if e.g. the file name ends in `.c`.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm using C++ because the XML I'm using has support only for C++. (2) Not really. In the examples, strings were handled this way, and I never thought of doing differently.

Comment: @LorenzoMoscati This is libxml2 and it is written in C, isn't it?

Comment: @uneven_mark AFAIK libxml2 is for C++, or so I thought. But if you tell me that it's written in C, then I'm willing to switch to C.

Comment: @LorenzoMoscati I suggest you simply compile with `gcc` instead of `g++` and see what happens. This is not likely to resolve your current issue, but would allow you to tag `C` and avoid comments about style problems such as my earlier ones and also direct the question to the crowd that is closer to the programming style you are using.

Comment: @paulsm4 I've added the backtrace as you asked.

Comment: @paulsm4 You wrote "I suspect not allocating space for "*name" could be the problem", but to which "*name" were you referring to? The Delegate's one or the Speaker's one? Also, how much space would you allocate to it since the name has variable length?

Comment: Try running your code though valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: 1) Your stack trace strongly suggests that you're "overwriting memory".  The question is "where?".  2) Valgrind might help.  3) Examining every pointer variable might be easier/faster than using Valgrind - that's your call.  4) The places where you've got "*name" pointers (*ALL* the places!) are likely suspects.  The standard C library function [strdup()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) could help mitigate the problem: it calls "malloc()" for you.

Comment: You have to reset `t` and `d` for each subnode. Simply declare both variables at the top of the first loop body.

Comment: @nwellnhof you're right, I'm trying to write over the array index. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @nwellnhof you're right. I'll write a proper answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nwellnhof pointed out in the comments, the problem of this code snippet is that the variables `d` and `t` I use to store the delegates and topics values are never reset to 0, so every cycle they grow up, trying to store the values in non-allocated memory space, resulting in an undefined behaviour.

The correct code is the following:

```cpp
static void load_prop() {

  xmlDocPtr doc;
  xmlNodePtr node;
  xmlNodePtr subnode;
  xmlNodePtr subsubnode;
  xmlNodePtr subsubsubnode;
  xmlChar *cnumber;

  doc = xmlParseFile("/Users/username/Documents/Obermun/DebateProgram/res/xml/property.xml");
  node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

  edition = (char *) xmlGetProp(node, (const xmlChar *) "edition");

  int const index = atoi((const char*)(xmlGetProp(node, (const xmlChar *) "committees")));
  committees = (struct Committee *) malloc(sizeof(struct Committee)*index);

  subnode = node -> xmlChildrenNode;
  int i = 0;
  int t = 0;
  int d = 0;

  while(subnode != NULL) {

    if(!xmlStrcmp(subnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "committee")) {

      committees[i].name = strdup((char *) xmlGetProp(subnode, (const xmlChar *) "name"));
      committees[i].n_delegate = atoi((const char*) xmlGetProp(subnode, (const xmlChar *) "delegates"));
      committees[i].delegates = (struct Delegate *) malloc(sizeof(struct Delegate)*committees[i].n_delegate);

      subsubnode = subnode -> xmlChildrenNode;

      t = 0;
      d = 0;

      while(subsubnode != NULL) {

        if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "topic")) {

          committees[i].topics[t] = strdup((char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1));
          t++;

        }

        else if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "delegate")) {

          committees[i].delegates[d].warnings = atoi((const char*) xmlGetProp(subsubnode, (const xmlChar *) "warnings"));
          committees[i].delegates[d].name = strdup((char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1));
          d++;

        }

        else if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "staff")) {

          subsubsubnode = subsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode;

          while(subsubsubnode != NULL) {

            if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "president")) {

              committees[i].staff.president = strdup((char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1));

            }

            if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "vice")) {

              committees[i].staff.vice = strdup((char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1));

            }

            if(!xmlStrcmp(subsubnode -> name, (const xmlChar *) "mod")) {

              committees[i].staff.mod = strdup((char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, subsubsubnode -> xmlChildrenNode, 1));

            }

            subsubsubnode = subsubsubnode -> next;

          }

        }

        subsubnode = subsubnode -> next;

      }

      i++;

    }

    subnode = subnode -> next;

  }

}
```

Notice `t` and `d` being set to 0 prior every cycle.